# Struggling with a scenario in DataWeave

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4

The below is the incoming sample payload. It has a field "Name" which can have any value eg, XYZ, PQR, ABC, and a specific value "TEST".

Incoming payload:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "XYZ",
    "Maths": "90",
    "English": "85"
  },
  {
    "Name": "ABC",
    "Maths" : "91",
    "English": "90"
  },
  {
    "Name": "TEST",
    "Maths" : "89",
    "English": "86"
  },
]
```

Below is a response from a database that has a list of values.
The Incoming payload Names need to be compared with the "Name" field in the database objects.

Data from different application =

```
[ 
  {"Name": "ABC",
   "Gender": "Female",
    "Class": "4"},

  {"Name": "PQR",
   "Gender": "Male",
    "Class": "5"},

  {"Name": "XYZ",
   "Gender": "Female",
    "Class": "3"},
  
 {"Name": "OPQ",
    "Gender": "Female",
    "Class": "3"},
  ...
]
```

If the "Name" in one or more of the objects in the Incoming payload is "TEST" then that object(s) needs to be skipped and the rest of the **matching** Names' objects should be the output; however, if the "Name" in any single object doesn't match with the list of Names in database response, then all the objects need to be skipped and an **empty payload should be the output** [].

In the above case, Names in incoming payload- XYZ, ABC are present in the database so below is the expected output(the TEST name object needs to be skipped):

```
 [
      {
        "Name": "XYZ",
        "Maths": "90",
        "English": "85"
      },
      {
        "Name": "ABC",
        "Maths" : "91",
        "English": "90"
      }
    ]
```

In the below scenario incoming payload has "Name" as "Stack" in one of the objects and "Stack" is not present in database response objects, so the empty payload output:

```
[
      {
        "Name": "XYZ",
        "Maths": "90",
        "English": "85"
      },
      {
        "Name": "ABC",
        "Maths" : "91",
        "English": "90"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Stack",   ----Not present in database response objects
        "Maths" : "91",
        "English": "90"
      }
    ]
```

Expected output:
[]

Comment: In the second use-case the incoming payload also has "XYZ" and "ABC" as Names which should then output the fields corresponding to those instead of [] since they are present in the database as well?

Comment: hi @SalimKhan even if a single object comparison fails whole payload needs be empty [], even if others match; But if others match and one of the object has name 'Test' ; then in that case only 'Test' object needs to be skipped, not all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this approach:

**Input**

```
[
  {
    "Name": "XYZ",
    "Maths": "90",
    "English": "85"
  },
  {
    "Name": "ABC",
    "Maths" : "91",
    "English": "90"
  },
  {
    "Name": "TEST",
    "Maths" : "89",
    "English": "86"
  }
]
```

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var compareWith = [ 
  {"Name": "ABC",
   "Gender": "Female",
    "Class": "4"},

  {"Name": "PQR",
   "Gender": "Male",
    "Class": "5"},

  {"Name": "XYZ",
   "Gender": "Female",
    "Class": "3"},
  
 {"Name": "OPQ",
    "Gender": "Female",
    "Class": "3"}
  
]

var inputNames = payload.Name

---

if (inputNames contains "TEST") payload filter(compareWith.Name contains $.Name) else if(sizeOf(payload filter(compareWith.Name contains $.Name)) != sizeOf(payload)) [] else payload
```

**Output**

```
[
  {
    "Name": "XYZ",
    "Maths": "90",
    "English": "85"
  },
  {
    "Name": "ABC",
    "Maths": "91",
    "English": "90"
  }
]
```

Comment: hi, this is almost working; however, this is not outputting empty payload if in incoming one object has 'TEST' and one other object doesn't match data with compareWith variable. In that case also empty output is the requirement. So to summarize, if any of the incoming object has unmatched Name, then empty payload - doesn't matter if 'TEST' is present in other object.

Comment: var final = payload filter ((item, index) -> item.Name != "TEST")
---

if(final map (compareWith..Name contains $.Name) contains false) ([]) else final  //this worked